# How to Avoid Duplication in Listview android

Tags: android, listview, assert, android-external-storage

Hai i am learning to acess a database file from assert folder
here i attach my external db images

i sucessfully added title fields in listview sucessfully but the titles are repeated in both db and my output but i need only one breakfast,dinner,lunch
how can we do this??

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listView;
SqlLiteDbHelper dbHelper;
FoodSupply foodSupply;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Cursor cursor;
TitleAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
    try {
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //foodSupply= new FoodSupply();
    sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=dbHelper.gettitles(sqLiteDatabase);
   adapter= new TitleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 if (cursor.moveToFirst())
   {
       do {
           String title;
           title=cursor.getString(0);
          foodSupply= new FoodSupply(title);
           adapter.add(foodSupply);

       }while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
 }
```

My Database class

```
public Cursor gettitles(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor;
    cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT Title FROM food_details",null);

        return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a raw query. Instead use a SQLiteDatabase.query implementation with the first distinct boolean set to true like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true, "YOUR_TABLE", new String[]{"Title"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

this should give only one of each.

EDIT:

this is the documentation from Google for this: 
[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal))

Comment: thanks :) but y we put true ??db.query(true) what is the reason??

Comment: I think you found it but for later users: The first parameter of .query is distinct. This tells the query to get only one distinctive value from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Before you attach data to the adapter, you can use a `Set` to eliminate repeating items. Then attach the set to the adpater.

Comment: can u say how to implemet plz??